# Outlook attachments.Add() is not showing in mail body

Tags: c#, outlook, office-2007

I'm creating a new mail item, in C# VS-2008 outlook 2007, and attaching a file.  The first issue is that I don't see an attachment area under the subject line showing the attachment.  If I send the e-mail its properties show that there is an attachment and the e-mail size has grown by the attachment amount.  I just cannot see it or extract the attachment.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)this.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
attachments.Add(ReleaseForm.ZipFile, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 0, "DisplayName");
```

I am expecting the part "DisplayName" would show as the attachment name and I should be using the filename.

I don't call .Send() on the e-mail programmatically, I call mailItem.Display(true) to show the e-mail to the user for any final edits.  At this point I can look at the properties and see that there is an attachment there.

If I press send (sending to myself) I see the same thing, the attachment appears to be there but not accessible.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the issue.  I change the code to use the following:

```
attachments.Add(ReleaseForm.ZipFile, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

It appears that the Position and DisplayName parameters control what happens with an olByValue.  Using Type.Missing and now I see the attachments correctly in the e-mail.

Answer (score 3):

By the way, if you will set Position to 0 your attachement will be hidden:

[Attachment.Position Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachment.position.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I  have excactly problem as yours, but even I change the code as yours, but it seems not work still. again, it seems already in the mailitems but not display on the mail items display.
OK, you have to make sure the mailItem body is not null to diplay the attechament

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an old post, but as some others mentioned, using

```
attachments.Add(path, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

did not help me either, so I thought I would share an alternative approach. The solution to this problem ended up being to call `mailItem.Save();` right before you call `mailItem.Display(true);`. What this will do is refresh the outlook form to show your attachments. It also worthwhile to point out that it will save the message to drafts. Not an issue if you expect the user to send the email, but if they cancel, it will be left in their Drafts folder.